# Get minimum period of non-equidistant sigal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have non-equidistant timestamps and according values like

```
sample_timestamp    powerdemand_in_kw_avg_sum
0   1.539009e+09    2.164672e+01
1   1.539009e+09    3.483988e+01
2   1.539010e+09    1.319316e+01
3   1.539014e+09    1.818989e-15
4   1.539021e+09    2.061695e+00
[...]
```

I would like to transform it to an equidistant signal. According to Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem I should choose the sampling frequency smaller than half the minimum period. How can I get the minimum period (using Python)?

Sorry if there is some technical incorrecness, I am new to telecommunications.

Answer (score 0):

To get the minimum difference between two timestamps, you can use [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.Series.shift) method

```
(df['sample_timestamp'] - df['sample_timestamp'].shift(1)).min()
```

I'm not an expert in telecommunications, the rest is up to you.